# Checking several If conditions in C randomly

Tags: c, if-statement

I have a program in C programming language in which there are several if conditions like below:
    `if(condition 1) {instructions}

 if(condition 2) {instructions}

 if(condition 3) {instructions}

 // and some other conditions`
Is there anyway that, when I run the program each time, the checking order of Ifs rearranged randomly e.g. like below:
    `if(condition 3) {instructions}

 if(condition 1) {instructions}

 if(condition 2) {instructions}

 // and some other conditions`

Comment: No direct way; but perhaps `switch(random() % 6) case 0: if (cond0) {instr0;}` could inspire you (for 6 conditions)

Answer (score 5):

You could:

- put each `if(conditition) { instructions }` in a function so that each function has the same signature
- create an array of function pointers to the functions
- shuffle the array
- go through the array and call each member

(Alternatively, if you're concerned about fn-call overhead but not standard compliance, you could replace the function pointers with GNU computed gotos).

---

Below is an example based computed gotos, which are here used as cheaper, addressable functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void shuffle(void *obj, size_t nmemb, size_t size);

#define ARRAY_SIZE(A) (sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]))

int main(int c, char **v)
{
    int n = c>1 ? atoi(v[1]) : 0;
    void *ret=&&ret_lbl;
    int i;
    srand(time(0));

    void *checks[] = { &&lt_10, &&lt_100, &&lt_1000, &&lt_10000 };
    shuffle(checks, ARRAY_SIZE(checks), sizeof checks[0]);

    for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE(checks); i++){
        goto *checks[i];
        ret_lbl:;
    }

return 0;

    /*the if checks*/

    lt_10: if (n < 10)  puts("lt_10");
           goto *ret;
    lt_100: if (n < 100)  puts("lt_100");
           goto *ret;
    lt_1000: if (n < 1000)  puts("lt_1000");
           goto *ret;
    lt_10000: if (n < 10000)  puts("lt_10000");
           goto *ret;

}


/* From 
   http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#C
*/
int rrand(int m)
{
  return (int)((double)m * ( rand() / (RAND_MAX+1.0) ));
}

#define BYTE(X) ((unsigned char *)(X)) 
void shuffle(void *obj, size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
  void *temp = malloc(size);
  size_t n = nmemb;
  while ( n > 1 ) {
    size_t k = rrand(n--);
    memcpy(temp, BYTE(obj) + n*size, size);
    memcpy(BYTE(obj) + n*size, BYTE(obj) + k*size, size);
    memcpy(BYTE(obj) + k*size, temp, size);
  }
  free(temp);
}
```

Comment: _put each if(conditition) { instructions } in a function so that each function has the same signature_  - that wrap will be actually optimized out by the compiler

Comment: @PeterJ Function calls through the pointers should effectively prevent inlining (especially since the pointers aren't constant due to the shuffling process).